# Need a way assign a value in a Select loop and use it per select

Tags: sql-server

This is what I thought to do first.

**Example**

```
  DECLARE @ID INT
  SET @ID = 0

  SELECT    
      @ID = ID, 
      TOTAL = @ID + 5
  FROM 
      Bank
```

This error occurs:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Is there other approach for this?

EDIT2:

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTab (id int)

INSERT INTO #tempTab (id) VALUES (5), (10)

DECLARE @SampleA INT
DECLARE @SampleB INT
DECLARE @SampleC INT

SELECT 
    @SampleA = 5*ID, --Row1 = 25, Row2 = 50
    @SampleB = @SampleA, - 15 --Row1 = 10, Row2 = 35
    @SampleC = @SampleA * @SampleB --Row1 = 250, Row2 = 1750
FROM
    #tempTab
```

Output I need is

```
-    25   |   10  | 250   -row1
-    50   |   68  | 1750  -row2
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ive editer my post to make it clearer. please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Derived Tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/):

```
SELECT ID, SampleA, SampleB, ( SampleA * SampleB ) AS SampleC
FROM(
    SELECT ID, SampleA , ( SampleA - 15 ) AS SampleB
    FROM(
        SELECT ID, 5 * ID AS SampleA
        FROM #tempTab
        ) AS A
    ) AS B
```

Output:

```
ID          SampleA     SampleB     SampleC
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
5           25          10          250
10          50          35          1750
```

Comment: It works, Thanks. Is there other different approach?

Comment: @Exequiel, you can use temporary tables (or table variables) to hold your intermediate calculation results.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest answer for your question.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTab (id int)
INSERT INTO #tempTab (id) values (5)
INSERT INTO #tempTab (id) values (10)



SELECT  (5*ID), --Row1 = 25, Row2 = 50
        5*ID - 15, --Row1 = 10, Row2 = 35
        (5*ID) * (5*ID - 15) --Row1 = 250, Row2 = 1750
FROM #tempTab 


SELECT * FROM #tempTab


DROP TABLE #tempTab
```

Comment: Thank for the response.Yes, its good for small data and computation. but i have a lot computation in my project. if i use that it'll be hard to read and bulky.